# Create Transparent Margin Between View And listView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a view that contains a title and a list view:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<View style={styles.header}>
<Text> {listViewTitle} </Text>
</View>
<ListView ........./>
```

And the styles:

```
container: {
       flex: 1,    
        backgroundColor:'white',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
    header: {
        backgroundColor: '#d4d4d6',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10
    }
```

---

These is the result:

- [Space Between Title And listView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9uDo.png)

The problem is that when I scroll I see the margin I have added between the title and listView:

[Blank Space When I Start Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqriG.png)

Is it possible to add a transparent space between the title and the listView so that when I start scrolling the space will not be visible anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `paddingTop: 10` to ListView and remove marginBottom from header.